# Firebase audiences - cannot target by user property

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Given that I can `firebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("some_property", someValue)`, it would be reasonable to expect that I can create an audience based on the certain user property right?

Can't find such option in Firebase console
[image]

It's not clear in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/config-analytics) either

**Side notes**

I know that I can target audiences by one property `user_id` which is set through `firebaseAnalytics.setUserId(someId)` but that's not what I want